# how to put screen size and uiview in ratio format to work for all screen

Tags: ios, uiview

i have `2 UIView` in horizontal view. its both `UIView` size is `141 x 192`.when i run in 5s screen the two view are in perfect. But when i run in 6,6s my `UIView` width is stretched. not able to see the correct width.

so how to code - **use the screen size and display the correct width and hight equal for all screen** using objective c

i used storyboard to fix 2 `UIView`. i am new to ios. how to code the `UIView` with position and also the aspect ration of screen size to see my `UIView` equal for all screen

Comment: can you upload an example image of how you want your views to be laid out?

Comment: i updated .kindly check it

Comment: Use custom width according to below formula or Use AutoLayout for that :- View.frame = CGRectMake(xspace, yspace, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - spaceUWantToPut)/2, viewHeight);

Comment: ok. so both views in addition shall take up the whole width, right? but how is the height calculated? is there a specific aspect ratio? or should they also take up the whole screen height?

Comment: no whole screen hight or width. only it should be fit with all screen with the same width and hight

Answer (score 1):

You can use autolayout and size classes for making user interface for multiple screen. First enable autolayout and size classes

[image]

Then you can give your views proportional width and height. For example in your case both view width will get 50% of screen width.

Since this is very detail topic. I will share a very simple and beginner tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Follow the tutorial and learn how to use autolayout.